# Creating CSS and JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, css, ubuntu, pycharm

Is it possible to create CSS and JavaScript files in PyCharm Community Edition? I've tried in mine but it's not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, to use **PyCharms web development tools** (e.g. CSS / JS), you need the PyCharm Professional Edition. Check out [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) comparision between Professional and Community: